# Next.js locale files are getting 404 because of setting basePath?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-i18next

Locale files are getting 404 , because of adding basePath ,

What i have tried **i18n.tsx**

```
  const NextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['de'],
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  localeSubpaths,
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
})

Updated above code with basePath like below ,

  const NextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['de'],
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  localeSubpaths,
  localePath: path.resolve('./<basepath>/public/static/locales'),
})
```

But this is throwing internal server error.

Comment: did u set up next.config.js

Comment: Which version of next js are you using ?

Comment: next - latest 
"next-i18next": "7.0.1",
@SomeoneSpecial yes next.config.js setup done

Comment: so these code is inside next.config.js can u show us your next.config.js ? and you shouldn't need to add base path to your locale path, those path are absolute to your files. base paths are virtual.

Comment: or maybe use /public/<basepath>/static/locales - https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/860 because the codes replace '/public' 'with ''

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks fixed it by this configuration in **i18n.tsx** Need to add backend in i18n.tsx

```
  const NextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
     backend: {
      loadPath: `https://${apiDomainName}/<basepath>/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
     },
  })
```

**apiDomainName** can be localhost:3000 or [www.your-webiste.com](http://www.your-webiste.com)